# Is this sentence construction wrong, where "going home" has other implied meaning, the origin and span of which isn't known?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity, phrase-origin, transatlantic-differences

I stumbled upon [this article](https://globalgraduates.com/articles/20-bizarre-english-idioms-and-how-to-explain-them) about the origins of some unusual idioms and phrases, as I have heard many of them being used popularly.

But I was bit shocked and frustrated when I read this sentence which seems to be constructed wrongly(even though it is only created to exemplify a different phrase).

> Pixie should never have gone home in that Dance-Off. She wiped the floor with Simon.

Was there any separate, short-lived, short-spanned phrase "going home" where it means any style of dance like "free style" or "original style" / "ethnic style" which could represent a knowledge of unique moves which his/her dance(or any activity) competitor doesn't know of ?

Because I have never heard of(or stumbled upon while researching) any sentence where "going home" means anything other than just **going home**

Comment: If Pixie lost the contest, then maybe they wanted to say she was _sent_ home...

Comment: If you read *both the sentences* because they are inter-related, you will find that *Pixie impliedly was great in the dance, as she wiped floor clean with Simon(her alleged competitor)*. So I am not convinced that they(judges) would send her home, it just doesn't fit/add-up.

Comment: I read both the sentences...I think you are missing the point.

Comment: Maybe, but still this feels like a(one of many) speculation, because if judges sent her home than Pixie doesn't have any other choice, so "should never have gone home" indicates *she had a choice* which looks incorrect unavoidably, thanks for comment though

Comment: It's one of those one-at-a-time knockout competitions, and when you're knocked out you're said to "go home". Local idioms are incredibly common in any group with a common social goal, especially one that requires judges, who always adore "precise" terms. Plus, if the writer stooped to "wiped the floor with" in the last sentence, what's odd about a simple metaphor of "going home"?

Comment: That's actually more informative, so as per what you said, maybe the writer just wanted to finish the example by making it short and quick, but in that process writer did made the senctence end abruptly, giving rise to doubts about it's construction, still, thank you!

Comment: Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar...

Comment: Think I am getting the point now. It's just that I wasn't aware that anyone would post an example like it, where to understand the example clearly, one would have to make many assumptions. It's not that apparent to me as it would be to others, who are quite more familiar with the said event(knockout competitions).

Comment: It's what we call "lack of context". Throwaway sentences like that are only to support the target language, in this case "wipe the floor". I wouldn't fret over them...

Comment: When someone is/was (I'm not sure if it's all that common nowadays) sent off in a rugby match, they were said to have 'gone for an early bath'. 'Going home' is far more transparent. It is often used to mean 'having been knocked out' in snooker tournaments (or 'driving up the M6' if the commentator knows their geography).

Comment: Baseball uses “sent to the showers”.

Comment: The judges should have made her the winner.

Comment: The presenters and judges on Strictly Come Dancing actually use the term "going home" to refer to a contestant who has been eliminated. The author of the post is using the terminology  of the show. It's a bit like a computer engineer talking about "memory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Going home” here means that participant was eliminated from a reality TV competition (in this case, [Strictly Come Dancing](https://www.hellomagazine.com/film/2014121222414/simon-webbe-worries-public-hate-him/)).

It’s pretty a pretty common expression in this context. Here are some examples:

- [Elimination Tracker: Here’s Every Celeb Who’s Gone Home on Dancing With the Stars This Season (and Why!)](https://parade.com/1095886/mikebloom/who-went-home-on-dancing-with-the-stars-season-29/)
- [‘American Idol’s Disney Night — Did the Right People Go Home? (POLL)](https://www.tvinsider.com/770429/american-idol-disney-night-top-8-uche-dimitrius-graham/)
- [The first cut is the deepest: Nearly half of 'The Voice’ Season 19 contestants go home in one night](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/the-first-cut-is-the-deepest-nearly-half-of-the-voice-season-19-contestants-go-home-in-one-night-042300321.html)

The origin of this expression is likely [Survivor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivor_(franchise)), a show where the competitors are marooned on an island and losing means they literally have to leave and go home.

Comment: +1 I don't get why people around here don't give the obvious answer an upvote/

Comment: This puts my mind to full rest finally, thank you, accepted..

Comment: @Lambie I think it is from burnout...

Comment: When you lose a competition, you go home. That's the main point. Or I guess you might head to the nearest bar.....I dunno, I stay away from competitions.